# JDialog for status display . .

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane, modality

I just want to implement a status dialog. How to show a JDialog which blocks the user input but allow the parent window processing its own work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a modal JDialog or JOptionPane (which really is nothing more than a specialized modal JDialog) for this, just be sure to

- the work is not to be done in a parent "window"
- but rather it should be done in a background thread
- and this thread should be started prior to setting the dialog visible.
- Use a SwingWorker for this background thread, and then your dialog can display quantitative progress information by adding a PropertyChangeListener and having the SwingWorker update its progress property.

Comment: PropertyChangeListener to what ??

Comment: @sanjeev to the `SwingWorker` it will fire `progress` property changed events (you need to examine the `PropertyChangeEvent` for the property name

Answer (score 2):

You can create and customize different kind of dialog using `JOptionPane`. Have a look at [JOptionPane Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features). Also, have to look at

- [JDialog(Dialog owner, boolean modal)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29)
- [ModalityTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29)
- The best of all could be [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)

Answer (score 2):

[JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) with `JOptionPane.showXXXDialog();` static methods, what else ?